# The domains of generators of Markov processes and moment of hitting times

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This is a question on domains of generators and moment of hitting times.

Let $M$ be a locally compact separable metric space and $X=(\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0}, \{P_x\}_{x \in M})$ a diffusion process on $M$ (that is $X$ is a strong Markov process with continuous sample paths). We assume that $X$ is symmetric with respect to a finite measure $\mu$ on $M$. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $E$. We also assume that $M \ni x \mapsto h(x):=E_{x}[e^{ \sigma_K}]$ is bounded on $M$, where $\sigma_K=\inf\{t \in [0,\infty) \mid X_t \in  K\}$. Then, can we show the following equation:
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad \mathcal{L}h=-h ?
\end{align*}
 Here, we denote by $\mathcal{L}$ the generator of $L^2$-generator of $X$. That is, $\mathcal{L}h$ is defined by $\mathcal{L}h=\lim_{t \to 0} (T_th-h)/t$ in $L^2(M,\mu)$. In a series of papers, the equation (1) is proved when $M$ is a smooth manifold and $X$ is a diffusion process on it. However, I think that (1) should hold under more general settings. It immediately follows that 
\begin{align*}
&\{T_th(x)-h(x)\}/t=\{E_x[E_{X_t}[e^{\sigma_K}]]-h(x)\}/t\\
&=\{E_{x}[e^{\sigma_K \circ \theta_t}]-E_{x}[e^{\sigma_K}]\}/t,
\end{align*}
where $\theta_t$ is the shift operator of $X$. However, I cannot proceed any further. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Can you supply the references?

Comment: @zab Thank you for your comment. For example, https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aihp/1359470127 is the reference.  In p. 102 of this paper, you can see the same equality.

Comment: The calculation should look like this: $E[h(X_t)|X_0=x]=E[E[e^{\sigma_K-t}|X_t]|X_0=x]=e^{-t}E[e^{\sigma_K}|X_0=x]=e^{-t}h(x).$
Therefore 
$$ \frac{T_th(x)-h(x)}{t} = \frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}h(x) \to -h(x).$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, your argument is not valid. Please notice that $\sigma_K=t+\sigma_K \circ \theta_t$ if $t<\sigma_K$. In general, $\sigma_K \le t+\sigma_K \circ \theta_t$.

Comment: Of course you are right. For small $t$ the probability that $\sigma_K<t$ is small, but I haven't found a way to derive good bounds.

Comment: @sharpe: $L h = -h$ only holds, in some sense, in the complement of $K$. "Some sense" here may refer to Itô calculus (meaning that $d M_t := dh(X_t) + h(X_t) dt$ defines a local martingale, up to $\sigma_K$), for example.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your kind comment. $t \mapsto h(X_{t \wedge \sigma_K})+\int_{0}^{t \wedge \sigma_K}h(X_s)\,ds$ is a local martingale, right?